# Need to find 2" utility sink drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

The plastic drain in a utility/laundry sink did not survive the attempt to remove or repair it.  The hole in the sink bottom is 2" in diameter.  There is a 3" diameter inset at the hole that limits the size of the drain's top flange. I have searched the web extensively and not found anything of appropriate size.  The closest I can get in appearance is an [Oatey 42099](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BO57AS); it unfortunately has a strainer that's over 3".

I hope I don't have to replace the sink!

Comment: What about a shower drain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "Laundry Tub Strainer". They are available at any good plumbing shop (notice I did not say "Big Box Home Improvement store") or online at what I think is the largest online retailer on earth (starts with A, ends with N, Z in the middle).

This one fits a 2" hole, the upper flange diameter is 2 3/4":

[image]

Specs are here:
[laundry tub strainer assembly](http://www.lasco.net/2-inch-outlet-c-2937_37_115_116/2-laundry-tray-plug-p-4403.html#.WfVQf1tSzcs**strong%20text**)